# Messenger Bot stops replying after some time

Tags: php, facebook-messenger-bot

I am developing messenger bot and it is working as expected most of the times. My problem is sometimes, bot stops replying after a while, I check my page is subscribed to the webhook, webhook is set up correctly and it seems as there is no reason that would make my bot to not reply. Any idea why would this happen? According to my research, bot stops replying mostly when page gets unsubscribed from the webhook, but that is not the case for sure as I use both command line and the ui to make sure it is subscribed correctly. Any help would be really appreciated.

P.S. For example if I come back after a day or so, bot will start replying again. It seems like it is passing some sort of upper bound and stops replying till that bound gets reset. (just random guess)

Comment: Where are you hosting your bot? Are you getting warnings from facebook that your webhook has become unresponsive? If your webhook begins to fail (does not return a status 200) FB will alert you in your developer account.

Comment: Sorry actually it was related to my code, it was giving 200 OK so I was not noticing the issue. But it is all good now